# Solving a set of simultaneous equation for periodic boundary conditions.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given $$g(x) = e^{-|x-x_0|/\alpha} + Ae^{-x/\alpha} + Be^{x/\alpha}$$
$\alpha >0$, $x_0 \in (0,1)$

Constraints are  $$g(0) = g(1)$$ and $$g'(0) = g'(1)$$

Solve for $A$ and $B$.

My solution : $$A = \frac{e^{(x_0-1)/\alpha}}{1-e^{(-1/\alpha)}}$$ and
$$B = \frac{e^{-x_0/\alpha}}{e^{1/\alpha}-1}$$

But when i verify, $g(0) \ne g(1)$. Certainly I am wrong and appreciate your help.

Edit : My differentiation
$$g'(x) = -\frac{sign(x-x_0)}{\alpha}e^{-|x-x_0|/\alpha} -\frac{A}{\alpha}e^{-x/\alpha} + \frac{B}{\alpha}e^{x/\alpha}$$

Comment: How do you differentiate $$g(x)$$ a function with absolute values?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : $$g'(x) = -\frac{sign(x-x_0)}{\alpha}e^{-|x-x_0|/\alpha} -\frac{A}{\alpha}e^{-x/\alpha} + \frac{B}{\alpha}e^{x/\alpha}$$